# Need Guidance on cPanel Backup APIs

Tags: cpanel, whm, cpanel-uapi

Currently, we are working on a Laravel project and utilizing cPanel APIs for creating and managing backups. We are facing an issue with the accuracy of the data returned by the list_backups API, which is hindering our ability to provide users with reliable information about their backups.

Here are the specific APIs we are using:

```
Back up cPanel account to home directory:
```

bash

> uapi --output=jsonpretty 
> --user=username 
> Backup 
> fullbackup_to_homedir

```
Return backup files:
```

bash

> uapi --output=jsonpretty 
> --user=username 
> Backup 
> list_backups

We suspect that the list_backups API may not be providing the correct backup data.

we are used

> uapi --output=jsonpretty 
> --user=username 
> Backup 
> fullbackup_to_homedir

this API and it's working fine we can see backup on home directory.

But we are not getting that backup in list

> uapi --output=jsonpretty 
> --user=username 
> Backup 
> list_backups

we need to provide restore option also so we need backup list for this but rightnow are not able to get that. we are getting backup from /backup directory and we required from /home/{username_directory}/backup_zip